# android singleinstance activity not single if back button pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, single-instance, launchmode

I encountered an interesting issue, where an Activity is created multiple times, even it is defined as a singleTask or a singelInstance Activity in the manifest. Here is how this can be reproduced. Say, in the main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.class, SingleActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

in my SingleActivity, I have:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Log.i("SingleActivity", "onCreate " + System.identityHashCode(this));
    ...
}
```

and in the manifest, I have:

```
    <activity android:name=".SingleActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    />
```

now, if I start the application, things seem OK, expect in one case: if I press the 'back' button while `SingleActivity` is in front, it navigates back to `MainActivity`, where `MainActivity.onResume()` will create another `SingleActivity` instance, instead of bringing forward the one that already exists. this is something I know because on the log, a different identity hash code is displayed.

the same seems to be true if the launch mode is singleTask.

the only workaround seems to be to override `onBackPressed()`, but that seems like an ugly solution.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Then you should vote for the answer that solved your problem, that's how Stackoverflow works!

Comment: oh, I see you're hunting karma points :) there you go...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, pressing the BACK key finishes (destroys) the current activity and displays the previous activity to the user.

So, this is impossible to

> instead of bringing forward the one that already exists

because no activity exists.

Comment: Are you sure the activity gets destroyed? I haven't looked at the code, but everytime I press back on my phone I can later resume the activity (it never gets destroyed).

Comment: this is happening to me

Answer (score 14):

This is a problem of `taskAffinity`. Because you haven't specified `taskAffinity` in the manifest on either your `MainActivity` or your `SingleActivity`, these 2 activities have the same (default) `taskAffinity`. When you start an activity, Android checks the `taskAffinity` of the activity that you want to start. If it is the same as the `taskAffinity` of the root activity in your task, then it will **ignore `launchMode="singleInstance"` or `launchMode="singleTask"`** (because those launch modes would require Android to create a new task to launch the activity in) and start the activity in the current task.

Unfortunately, this isn't well documented, but `taskAffinity` takes precedence over `launchMode`.

If you really want a `singleTask` or `singleInstance` activity (which is usually not the right thing to do because it brings with it a whole mess of other nasty things that you are likely to get wrong), then you need to make sure that your `singleInstance` or `singleTask` activity has the following in the manifest in its `<activity>` definition:

```
android:taskAffinity=""
```

If you need more information, search StackOverflow or Google for "launchmode taskaffinity"

Comment: If the all activities have finished, the task'll be  destoryed, so when re-start the activity, it'll re-create  activity even if the activity has specified the  `singleInstance` flag.

Comment: What do you mean by "it brings with it a whole mess of other nasty things that you are likely to get wrong"? In my case, I am using launchMode="singleInstance" and android:taskAffinity="" for my Launcher app and everything is OK.

Comment: @Pascal If you have multiple activities in your app, this gets complicated. Also if your app can be started by another app it gets complicated. In general, using `singleTask` or `singleInstance` causes more subtle behaviour problems than it solves. It is rarely necessary to use a special launch mode. Most people try using it to solve a problem that they don't really understand, in my experience.

Comment: OK. In my case I just do that in my Launcher and I have no problem with that. Thanks